# When are generators converted to lists in Dask?

Tags: python, dask

In Dask, when do generators get converted to lists, or are they generally consumed lazily?
For example, with the code:

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import dask.bag as db

def foo(n):
    for _ in range(n):
        yield np.random.randint(10)

def add_to_count(acc, x):
    acc.update(x)
    return acc

def add(x,y):
    return x + y

b1 = db.from_sequence([1,2,3,4,5])
b2 = b1.map(foo)
result = b2.fold(add_to_count, add, Counter())
```

I get the following output, where the generators
have (reasonably) been converted to lists for me to inspect:

```
>>> b2.compute()
[[5], [5, 6], [3, 6, 1], [5, 6, 6, 0], [5, 6, 6, 0, 3]]
```

While reasonable, it differs from how I usually expect generators to behave in Python, which would be to require an explicit conversion to a list.

So, when computing the `fold` (`result.compute()`),
is the input argument `x` of `add_to_count`
a generator, or has it already been converted to a list?

I'm interested in the case where the lists are very long,
and so lazy evaluation is more efficient, say,
`b1 = db.from_sequence([10**6]*10)`.

I'm guessing I could also solve the above problem with `bag.frequencies`, but I have similar concerns about lazy evaluation and efficient reduction.

Is there a fundamental aspect of Dask that I'm not grokking, or am I just being lazy, and where could I have looked into the code to figure this out myself?

Comment: Well, easily enough, adding `print(type(x))` to `add_to_count()` and trying with the different schedulers seems to confirm that `x` is indeed a generator object. I'll leave this open for a bit in case there's anything to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly appropriate, but I'll provide the answer to a slightly different question:

Dask.bag adds in defensive calls to list` for you, just in case you decide to branch out and use the bag twice in a single computation:

```
x = b.map(func1, b)
y = b.map(func2, b)
compute(x.frequencies(), b.frequencies())
```

This is also useful when using backends like multiprocessing or distributed because we can't send generators across a process boundary, but can send lists.

However, these defensive calls to `list` are optimized away before computation when possible in an effort to promote laziness.

In summary, everything should *just work* the way you want when possible, but will revert to concrete non-lazy values when laziness would get in the way of correctness.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for. Is this outlined in the documentation anywhere (I couldn't find it), and would it be useful? If you think so, I could potentially take a stab at it with some help.